# Sort List<> not working as expected

Tags: java, string, list, sorting, comparator

How to sort `List<>` in java **a-z** or by **date** or anything from the **bigger to the lower** or **lower to bigger** etc?

I searched a lot about this and found the `Collections` to **only sort from a-z** but it's sort the uppercase first then the lowercase

ex:

```
// Must be like this
Best
best
Book
Bus

// But it's returns this
Best
Book
Bus
best
```

Also it's very slow, I see other apps loads sorted lists in 5 sec. and mine takes 15 or 20 sec!

The code:

```
Collections.sort(posts, new Comparator<Post>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Post lhs, Post rhs) {
                return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
            }
        });
```

Comment: 20 seconds? How long is the list? Is getName just a getter or is it doing some calculation?

Comment: list of installed apps with app sizes and other stuff.

Comment: It can't be the sort that's taking 20 seconds, surely?

Comment: yes it's, actually i don't know the reason behind this and why other apps make the calculations fast than me.

Comment: What is the size of the list `posts` that takes 20 seconds to sort? How long is the average String in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.toLowerCase()` to handle the issue with capitalization of your words:

```
Collections.sort(posts, new Comparator<Post>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Post lhs, Post rhs) {
            String left  = lhs.getName().toLowerCase();
            String right = rhs.getName().toLowerCase();

            if (left.equals(right)) {
                return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
            }
            else {
                return left.compareTo(right);
            }
});
```

If you also want to include things like size and date in the sort, you can modify the `compare()` method to take these into account.  For example to compare by name (first) and size (second), use this code:

```
Collections.sort(posts, new Comparator<Post>() {
     @Override
     public int compare(Post lhs, Post rhs) {
         int nameComp = lhs.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.getName());
         if (nameComp == 0) {
             Integer lhsSize = lhs.getSize();
             Integer rhsSize = rhs.getSize();

             return lhsSize.compareTo(rhsSize);
         }
         else {
             return nameComp;
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: Wierd, I tried this before and not working but now works!, Thanks, but what about the long time and other sort options like sort by size and things like this?

Comment: How large is the collection you are trying to sort?

Comment: I have 295 apps system and user so i think it's the same number

Comment: To be direct: Roughly how many `Post` objects will be in the collection, in total?  We are not familiar with the inner workings of your code.

Comment: are you sure that 20 seconds are spent in sorting but not other things?

Comment: @AdrianShum not just sorting, it's gets app sizes such apk size and data and some package info etc

Comment: @Stephan do some basic profiling and make sure what is the bottleneck.  Quite likely it has nothing to do with sorting.

Comment: Instead of using `String.toLowerCase()` and `compare()`, you should use `compareIgnoreCase()`.

Comment: I do all the work in one `AsyncTask` do i need to make stand alone task for calculations? @AdrianShum

Comment: 1. It has nothing to do with this question. Raise another one if you need.  2. No one can answer unless you have do profiling by yourself and find the bottleneck

Comment: Thanks to everyone for posting so many comments on my answer, when they really belonged on the question itself.

Comment: Okay, I will try again to find the problem about the long time, what about other sort types like sort by size and install date?, do i need to ask new question about this? @AdrianShum

Comment: I can answer this one: You can sort by multiple `Post` fields in your comparator.  If you update your question, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @Stephan Check my answer.  I have mentioned on how to sort on multiple fields

Answer (score 4):

It would probably be somewhat more efficient to use `String.compareToIgnoreCase` instead:

```
Collections.sort(posts, new Comparator<Post>() {
     @Override
     public int compare(Post lhs, Post rhs) {
         return lhs.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.getName());
     }
});
```

This way you don't create intermediate strings (like in @TimBiegeleisen answer), but compare them in-place.

Note that it's much simpler in Java-8:

```
Collections.sort(posts, Comparator.comparing(Post::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I looked and no, intermediage strings are not used. Only intermediate chars are created (which are not heap objects) and only up to the first difference. No reason to turn the whole string into lowercase if the first letter differs.

Answer (score 0):

A supplement of the existing answer.

The way to do case-ignored comparison by "first convert to lowercase then compare" is not effective because new `String` objects are unnecessarily created.

The more appropriate way is to use `String.compareIgnoreCase()` or by `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` comparator.

And, if OP is open to 3rd party libraries, using Guava or Apache Common Langs may make your code much easier to read if you are going to compare multiple properties, for example by using Guava:

```
Collections.sort(posts, new Comparator<Post>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Post lhs, Post rhs) {
        return ComparatorChain.start()
                .compare(lhs.getName(), rhs.getName(), String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
                .compare(lhs.getName(), rhs.getName())
                .compare(lhs.getDate(), rhs.getDate()) 
                .compare(lhs.getId(), rhs.getId())
                .result();
    }
});
```